# Two methods call from one url or different url

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have two methods such as `method1()` and `method2()`. Two methods are contained into two web **API** and published different **URL**. I can call that method from two **URL**'s like:

> www.aaa.com/api/firstcontroller/method1
>
> www.bbb.com/api/secondcontroller/method2

Or if create one web **API** and create two methods and publish into one URL such as:

> www.aaa.com/api/firstcontroller

**My questions:** which will be faster, if I call ***two methods from one URL*** or if I ***call two methods from different URL***.

Answer (score 1):

Well it will be fater to call 2 method from one **URL**, but only in case of bad connection to server, other way you will not notice any difference.

I hope you understand that if you want to do some methods really fast you should  parallel them on server side.

Comment: can you more explain that how can be faster call 2 method from one URL?.

Comment: you know that the total time of calling 2 methods from web can be calculated from sum of time of your request have been sended to server and time of method execution. So it's really simple, if you have slow net connection or bad chanel to your server request will be send really long time. On server your 2 methods will execute same time in bouth cases if you parallel them as i say.